# Indexing Huge text file

Tags: c++, windows, linux, matlab

I have one huge text file (over 100 gigs) with 6 columns of data (tab as separator). In first column I have integer value (2500 distinct values in set). I need to split this file into multiple smaller files depending on value in first column (note that rows are NOT sorted). Each of this smaller files will be used to prepare plot in matlab.

I have only 8 GB of ram.

The problem is how to do that efficiently? Any ideas?

Comment: "Only 8 GB of ram". Wow, we've come a long way.

Answer (score 5):

Using bash:

```
cat 100gigfile | while read line; do
  intval="$( echo "$line" | cut -f 1)"
  chunkfile="$( printf '%010u.txt' "$intval" )"
  echo "$line" >> "$chunkfile"
done
```

That will split your 100 gig file into (as you say) 2500 individual files named according the value of the first field. You may have to adjust the format argument to printf to your taste.

Comment: This will spawn a `cut` and a `printf` process and will open and close the `"$chunkfile"` for every line. Doesn't seem too efficient for a 100gig file.

Comment: @Marcelo - You might try running that in the background while designing the efficient solution. Wanna bet which program completes first?

Comment: @Bo Persson I expect hacking a slightly more efficient solution in your favourite RAD language (perl,python etc) would solve the problem in less elapsed time. a 100Gb file likely has more than a billion lines.

Answer (score 2):

one-liner with bash+awk:

```
awk '{print $0 >> $1".dat" }' 100gigfile
```

this will append every line of your large file to a file named as the first column's value + ".dat" extension, e.g. line `12 aa bb cc dd ee ff` will go to the `12.dat` file.

Comment: I've just started testing this solution - seems very simple.

Comment: @gozwei: indeed. I know very little of awk, but there are cases where it is indispensable

Answer (score 1):

For linux 64 bit (I am not sure if it works for windows), you can mmap the file, and copy blocks to new files. I think that this would be most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell...

```
$ split -d -l <some number of lines> Foo Foo
```

That will split a large file `Foo` into `Foo1` through `FooN` where n is determined by the number of lines in the original divided by the value you supply  to -l.  Iterate over the pieces in a loop...

**EDIT**... good point in the comment... this script (below) will read line by line, classify and assign to a file based on the first field...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

prefix = 'filename'
reader = csv.reader(open('%s.csv' % prefix, 'r'))
suffix = 0
files = {}
# read one row at a time, classify on first field, and send to a file
# row[0] assumes csv reader does *not* split the line... if you make it do so,
# remove the [0] indexing (and strip()s) below
for row in reader:
    tmp = row[0].split('\t')
    fh = files.get(tmp[0].strip(), False)
    if not fh:
        fh = open('%s%05i.csv' % (prefix, suffix), 'a')
        files[tmp[0].strip()] = fh
        suffix += 1
    fh.write(row[0])

for key in files.keys():
    files[key].close()
```

Comment: -1 because it does not answer the question. You have to have to decide to which file a line gets dumped into and `split` doesn't do so.

Comment: Aha - upon reading the question for the third time, I found that it was incomplete :)

Comment: one of the few cases where I prefer bash over python: one-liner with awk

Comment: @davka, will that oneliner read the file line-by-line, or as a continuous byte-stream?

Comment: do you mean what is the underlying i/o mode? I don't know. If you mean from user's perspective, then by line

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way will be block by block, opening all files at once, and re-use the read buffer for writing. As the information is provided, there is no other pattern in the data that could be used to speed it up.

You will open each file in a different file descriptor to avoid opening and closing with each line. Open them all at the beginning or lazily as you go. Close them all before finishing up. Most linux distributions will allow only 1024 open files by default, so you will have to up the limit, say using `ulimit -n 2600` given you have permission to do so (see also `/etc/security/limits.conf`).

Allocate a buffer, say a couple of kb, and raw read from the source file into it. Iterate though and keep control variables. Whenever you reach a endline or the end of the buffer write from the buffer into the correct file descriptor. There are a couple of edge cases you'll have to take into account, like when a read gets a newline but not enough to figure out which file should go into.

You could reverse-iterate to avoid processing the first few bytes of the buffer if you figure out the minimum line size. This will prove to be a bit trickier but a speed up nonetheless.

I wonder if non-blocking I/O takes care of problems such as this one.

Comment: Well, the tag on the question is c++ and the question is on efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to open a new file every time you encounter a new value, and keep it open until the end. But your OS might not allow you to open 2500 files at once. So if you only have to do this once, you might do it this way:

1. Go through the file, building a list of all the values. Sort this list. (You don't need this step if you know in advance what the values will be.)
2. Set StartIndex to 0.
3. Open, say, 100 files (whatever your OS is comfortable with). These correspond to the next 100 values in the list, from `list[StartIndex]` to `list[StartIndex+99]`.
4. Go through the file, otuputting those records with `list[StartIndex] <= value <= list[StartIndex+99]`.
5. Close all the files.
6. Add 100 to `StartIndex`, and go to step 3 if you haven't finished.

So you need 26 passes through the file.